# How far do you have to progress through Pokémon Ultra Sun / Ultra Moon to access Mystery Gift?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

I have some of those “Mystery Gift” legendary codes about to expire, but haven’t had time to play the game.  Normally access to Mystery Gift is locked down initially and activates later.

How much progress do I need to make to be able to activate them? (That is, what event triggers access, and how much playtime is required to get there?)

Comment: I can't remember exactly, because it's been a while, but I think you can either access mystery gifts without a save file at all, or do so as soon as you save for the first time. The menu option is on the title screen so I don't think it even requires a save. If you can try that and it works I'll post an answer.

Comment: You would need a save; starting the game without a save file takes you right to the introduction, rather than to the main menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know what the absolute earliest is, but I used the code after I went to the Pokémon Centre (having been given the Rotom Dex) and it worked at that point, around an hour in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mystery Gift as soon as you start a new save file.

Answer (score -1):

Margaret, after you get the rotom dex save your game, exit and enter the game, when you see your saved file underneath the save file is the mystery gift button you should also be able to get a level 10 rockruff via the internet button there.
Pokemon Kid

Comment: The Rockruff event is no longer occurring.